# Mixing tips and techniques

Tags: mixing

Lately I've seen tons of mixing tutorials. Mainly produce like a pro, Pensaudo's place and recording evolution. But still when I try these techniques I feel that my mix still doesn't sound right. 90% of my tracks are Logic's stock plugins. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How many years have you been doing this? if the answer is less than 10, then you've still a way to go. Just keep practising.

Comment: It’s hard to say what you are doing wrong, without hearing what you do...

Answer (score 1):

Using side chain/ducking can go a long way towards clarifying rhythms and lead vocals. When ducking the bass against the kick drum, the bass level is dropped for a moment allowing space for the easily lost in the mix kick drum to be heard. This does a lot of good for the song's "tightness" and for defining the song's groove.